# How to run h2o models for each category separately?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, h2o

For each category I need to fit h2o model.

```
  Category            a             b
       <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>
     1   aa           36.6          1.4
     2   aa           5.30          0   
     3   bb           4.62          1.2
     4   bb           3.71          1.5
     5   cc           3.41          12
    ... ...            ...         ...
```

Is it possible to do it without splitting dataset on categories and running training on each category in the loop. Is it possible to do with dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For each category I need to fit h2o model.
>   Is it possible to do it without splitting dataset on categories...

No.

You need the loop, and to build one model for each level in the enum (to use the h2o terms).  (To get a list of all values in a category see http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.levels  )

If your requirements were more fuzzy, then you can use a single model. I.e. if you think that the "chr" category is the most useful piece of information you have for predicting some other value, you could just build a model (e.g. random forest), and if you are right that will be the top-level split in every tree, and you will effectively get what you want.

But if this is for an academic report, or for regulatory reasons, and you need to show predictions split by your "chr" column, then you have no other way.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't make it with `h2o` but maybe it can help you:

```
  iris%>%
   group_by(Species)%>%
   nest()%>%
   mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = .x)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    data              fit     
  <fct>      <list>            <list>  
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]> <S3: lm>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]> <S3: lm>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]> <S3: lm>
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't run models from h2o on r dataframes. h2o uses H2OFrame. So I can't use group_by from dplyr as I can't figure out how to make h2o.group_by work like dplyr group_by. I stucked with it.